# How to select a discrete area in an image?

Tags: python, scikit-image

In an image with some discrete areas, how can I point the mouse and select the whole area?

In the image, how to select the whole red area?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you need, is an automated or semi-automatic image segmentation algorithm.

I think, what you describe in your question, is known as the Watershed algorithm which is a simple automatic image segmentation method:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watershed_(image_processing)

An alternative approach would be a semi-automatic segmentation solution, such as the active contour (greedy snakes) algorithm:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_contour_model

A snake is an energy minimizing, deformable spline influenced by constraint and image forces that pull it towards object contours and internal forces that resist deformation.

Implementations for both of the aforementioned algorithms in python can be found here:

http://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.segmentation.html

Comment: Thank you very much! the watershed method worked perfectly for my case even though it takes me a little bit time to understand how to use the skimage.segmentation.watershed function. can you recommended any website or books to learn detail of those algorithms?

Comment: Check the resources section of the wiki pages I mentioned. Also, check for video tutorials on youtube. There should be some image processing and computer vision textbooks discussing further details, but as long as you don't want to improve the algorithm further you should be fine even without knowing many details about how it works.